# Configuring Nginx/NChan

Tags: nginx

In a mobile app that I developing I use WebSockets to subscribe/publish a range of different information.  In most instances the app side websocket is simply a listener.  However, there are times when it does also publish a message.

Server side I am handling this using a combination of [NChan][1] working on top of Nginx.  One of the really nice features of NChan is the ability to "multiplex" a websocket - i.e. have it pub/sub on multiple channels.  When creating a mobile app this goes a long way to improving tidiness and battery friendliness.

As explained in the [NChan documentation][2] I have set up multiplexed `pubsub`channels

```
location ~ /pubsub/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ 
{
 nchan_pubsub;
 nchan_channel_id "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "control";
 nchan_publisher_upstream_request /alter;
}
```

The third line above, `chan_publisher_upstream...` forwards incoming `pub`requests to another server

```
location = /alter 
{
 proxy_pass https://example.com;
 proxy_set_header X-Publisher-Type $nchan_publisher_type;
 proxy_set_header X-Prev-Message-Id $nchan_prev_message_id;
 proxy_set_header X-Channel-Id $nchan_channel_id;
 proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

On the other server I have set up Nginx to run PHP with `index.php` in the server root folder reading

```
<?php
 trigger_error(json_encode(getallheaders()));//a test to see that the proxy pass is actually 
 happening
 
 header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
 //if successful should cause the incoming request to be published without changes
 
 //header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content");
 //when enable will suppress the incoming request (optionally after doing some server-side
 //stuff with the incoming request data

 //header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
 //echo 'New Content!';
 //when enabled should replace the incoming requestt content with the new one 
 ?>
```

As far as I can tell I have followed the NChan instructions quite diligently.  However, when I attempt to use this configuration to publish on the now defined `pubsub` channel the client connection is unexpectedly being closed down.  To perform this test I am using some simple JavaScript

```
    var socket;

    function connectPubSub()
    {
     socket = new WebSocket("wss://app.server.url/pubsub/personal/cause/beacon/grid/chat");
     socket.onopen = whenOpen;
     socket.onmessage = whenMessage;
     socket.onclose = whenClose;
     socket.onerror = whenError;
    } 

    function whenOpen(e){console.log("[open] Connection established");}

    function whenMessage(event){console.log(`[message]:${event.data}`);}

    function whenClose(event) 
    {
     if (event.wasClean) 
      alert(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
      else console.log('[close] Connection died');
    }

    function whenError(error){console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);}

    function sendMessage(msg){socket.send(msg);}
```

At this point when I try to issue the following

```
connectPubSub();
sendMessage('Hello world!');
```

I get the output shown below

```
[open] Connection Established
Websocket connection to app.server.url failed:Close received after close
```

The error event is as shown below

```
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: WebSocket {url: "wss://app.server.url/pubsub/personal/cause/beacon/grid/chat", 
readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
path: []
returnValue: true
srcElement: WebSocket {url: "wss://app.server.url/pubsub/personal/cause/beacon/grid/chat", 
readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
target: WebSocket {url: "wss://app.server.url/pubsub/personal/cause/beacon/grid/chat", 
readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: ƒ, onerror: ƒ, …}
timeStamp: 83208.4250000189
```

This has me stumped. I thought I would simply be able to follow the NChan docs and publish messages
on the multiplexed `pubsub`channel, then examine the message content (JSON) on my proxy server prior to deciding what to do

- Let the message through (issue an HTTP 304)
- Take server-side action & then suppress the message (issue an HTTP 204)
- Modify the message and send it on (issue an HTTP 200)

My rather sketchy knowledge of Nginx configuration directives is probably letting me down here. What am I doing wrong?

---

I have now been able to establish what is going on here.  The root of the problem here appears to bee the

proxy_pass https://example.com;

directive.  If I change it to

```
proxy_pass https://example.com/index.php;
```

things work as expected.  However, it is still not clear to me why this might be happening.  The top of my Nginx default configuration file has the lines

```
server 
{
 root /path/to/root;
 index index.php;

 server_name example.com;
```

I thought the third line above, `index index.php` is pretty much all I need to tell Nginx to execute index.php at any folder/subfolder location.  Clearly, not the case?
[1]: https://nchan.io
[2]: https://nchan.io/#getting-started

Comment: No, that does not work.